# Python logger erratic behavior with subprocess/threads sometimes

Tags: python, logging, subprocess

I have following observations about logger module of Python:
1. If a process is spawned using subprocess, logger module is not able to perform rollover
2. If multiple threads are running, logger module is unable to perform rollover
3. If main program spawns a process using subprocess (new process having no link to python/logger) and if main/original program is closed, it does not start giving error that logger is unable to access the log file. It is able to start only when the previously spawned process is closed using task manager.

What do you think is wrong here? I cannot paste code here as it is too large. Has anyone faced such issues here?

Comment: Please post a [short self-contained example](http://sscce.org/). One of two good things will happen: Either you will discover the basic structure you need and will be able to apply this to your larger project, or your question will be clarified to the point where we can offer accurate help.

Comment: I assume from "task manager" that you're on Windows. There, a file being kept open can prevent rollover. Files being kept open can happen when you spawn suprocesses without closing all file descriptors.